# SetState and push object in array in nested dynamic array of objects in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, setstate

I have two array with same objects properties and I wanted to update only specific object data from one array without affecting second array of object.

I have tried JSON parse but it didn't work because I am using drag n drop on data so I wanted to updated specific object passing index.

```
this.state = {
           listItem: [
            // This data will be static 
                { data: `Text`, content: 'Insert you text here...' },
                {
                    data: `Column`,
                    content: 'Column',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            column: []
                        },
                        {
                            column: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
           layout:[
           // The data below might be more than 3-4 times repetitive 
            {
                    data: `Column`,
                    content: 'Column',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            column: []
                        },
                        {
                            column: []
                        }
                    ]
                }     
            ]
}

// Set State function I tried recently 
onColumnDrop(e, layoutIndex, colIndex) {

        if (e.removedIndex !== null || e.addedIndex !== null) {

            var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.layout);
            stateCopy[layoutIndex].columns[colIndex].column = e.payload;
            this.setState({ stateCopy });

        }
    }
```

So, basically the functionality is as I drag the object from listItem and drop in layout column array so I wanted to setState that dragged object in column[0] or column[1] array so the thing happening is when I keep pushing  listItem[0] in column[0] or column[1] array then at the same time its updating in listItem columns, don't know why! but I am super confused.

Comment: Can you share the code that is calling setState?

Comment: @Simran Here is function I am using for setState:

`code`
onColumnDrop(e, layoutIndex, colIndex) {

        if (e.removedIndex !== null || e.addedIndex !== null) {
      
            var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.layout);
            stateCopy[layoutIndex].columns[colIndex].colum = e.payload;
            this.setState({ stateCopy });

        }
    }`code`

Comment: Add to the question please, difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: @Simran Added the same in the question, Please review. Thanks

Comment: can you take some time to indent your code properly? @PravinGaikwad

Comment: Is the typo here: `stateCopy[layoutIndex].columns[colIndex].colum = e.payload;` the issue? `colum`??

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I have updated the formatted code in main question, Please check.

Comment: @Simran Sorry for that mistake but the issue is still there as if I update then its updating the same in listItem thats the main issue I am facing also in this setState method its creating a new array with name "stateCopy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very much like you have multiple references to the same object in your code and it is most likely the result of `var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.layout);`. This line copies the state only shallowly, which means, that objects and arrays deeper within the state will not be copied, but only the references to the objects will. So you basically end up mutating the original state, when you do `stateCopy[layoutIndex].columns[colIndex].colum = e.payload;`.

To avoid this problem, you either have to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))`, what seems to be not possible or you have to implement deep copying by your own, where you copy all levels of your state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually I had tried with JSON.parse but "layout" array objects has drag n drop feature which rendering again n again and cloning those objects in the array whenever I drag n drop those list items.

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)) worked for me, Thanks